# Android - Sending and receiving location updates of other users

Tags: android

I have already an location based app which functionality i want to expand:
A user can login to this App via Facebook and also other users are logged on their own Mobilephone. Both can see the location of the other.
So basically an location aware meet people APP :-)

How can I do this? Backend with PHP and mysql database?
Are there already existing solutions I can use?
Tutorials available describing this?!

Answer (score -1):

the infrastructure you need is achievable in many many programming languages and many types of databases.

In the end what you need is a server running that can store the location data sent from the users. Ideally i would tell you to use webservices in order to achieve this.

Next, you will need to implement a location service app that works on the user smartphone and uses the web services to send information and get information to and from the server.

Programming languagens you can achieve this are so many. For example, in the back end you can use a mysql database with a tomcat server. if u need a front-end for the server you can use java server pages, php, whatever u feel more confortable with.

for the mobile phone there are hybrid application for different OSs. for android specifically you will use java. if u want to save some info in the phones you can use a SQLite database. this is important if you want to send data only when internet connections are available.

Those are the kind of things you have to deal with. Hope i helped you.

Good luck.